# how to represent email data as input for classification based on discussion topic using weka?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, weka, document-classification

> Duplicate: [How to represent text for classification in weka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313426/how-to-represent-text-for-classification-in-weka)

What will be the input to the classifier if my data is Email, i.e, textual data? What will be the attributes/feature set in Email that I need to consider to perform classification based on discussion topic?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, one transforms the input data using TF-IDF into sparse vectors.